# is_prime and defining two functions

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am new to python. I have a question that asks the following

Write function `lst_prime()` that:

- takes a bound as an input, which is positive integer
- returns a list of prime numbers smaller than or equal to the bound.

the output answers I am supposed to match is:

```
>>> lst_prime(0)
[]

>>> lst_prime(6)
[2, 3, 5]

>>> lst_prime(11)
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
```

this is my code so far.

```
def lst_prime(n):
    def is_prime(m):
        for i in range(2, m):
            if n % i == 0:
                return True 
        return False 
    for i in range(n-1, 1, -1):
        if is_prime(i) == True: 
            return i
```

It is not giving me the correct output and it gives me an error message that says `is_prime` is not defined. Can someone please help me? Thank you.

Comment: Is there any reason to define `is_prime()` in `lst_prime()`? it seems not a good structure.

Comment: Your code or your error is not what you're using/getting; the code as written would not raise an error due to `is_prime` not being defined. Please provide a [MCVE] (including the calling code, the full traceback for exceptions, provided inputs, expected outputs, etc.). Side-note: A problem like this (`lst_prime`) is usually solved via the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes); trial division works for very small inputs, but it scales poorly (quadratically) to large inputs, where Eratosthenes scales roughly linearly (`O(n log log n)`, but close enough).

Comment: Please post the code that is calling this function or show the complete transcript from the interactive session where you define and/or import the function. Also include the whole traceback (the call stack dump that is printed when the exception is raised).

Answer (score 1):

Closer to what you seek:

- Skip over even numbers (except for 2)
- Only do the mod operations with already discovered prime numbers

Code:

```
def is_prime(x, primes):
    for p in primes:
        if (x % p) == 0:
            return False
    return True


def lst_prime(n):
     primes = []
     if (n < 2):
        return primes
     primes = [2]
     for i in range(3, n+1, 2):  # n+1 so that "n" can be evaluated as prime as well
         if is_prime(i, primes):
            primes.append(i)
     return primes
```

test:

```
>>> lst_prime(99)
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def lst_prime(prime_number_to_make_list_for):
    def is_prime(m):
        for j in range(2, m):
            print("{} %  {}= {}".format(m, j, m % j))
            if m % j == 0:
                return False
        return True
    prime_list = []
    for i in range(0, prime_number_to_make_list_for + 1):
        if is_prime(i):
            prime_list.append(i)
    return prime_list

my_list = lst_prime(15)
print(my_list)
```

For me this outputs:

> [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]

The problem was in your `if n % i == 0:` mainly I think, but your `True` and `False` were flip flopped as well...You should try to use `print()` statements to debug these things (I left one of mine in there as an example of how to do so) and also use descriptive variable names (instead of `i` twice and the very informative `n` and `m`...). I don't think you realized you were even doing the comparison to the same number every time you went through your inner loop.